# Retrieve all nearest points using GeoDjango

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I have to implement a new feature in my Django project: I have to retrieve all objects nearest a position (latitude, longitude) with distance = 5km

So, I use Postgres + PostGIS and I integrated GeoDjango.

In my models I have something like this:

```
class CarLocation(models.Model):

    carInfo = models.OneToOneField(CarInfo, related_name="carLocation")
    # Car location info
    geom = models.PointField(srid=4326, spatial_index=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

At this point I can make a query like this:

```
pnt = fromstr('POINT(-96.876369 29.905320)', srid=4326)
qs = CarLocation.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(pnt, D(km=5)))
```

I have some questions about this...

- Is this the best way?
- Is a good solution to have `CarLocation` model separated from `CarInfo` table? In my response I have to return also some informations that are contained into `CarInfo`.
- Is a good solution to have `spatial_index=True` in my model?
- If I have many points (for example 500-600k) is this still good? In this case, is possible to paginate the results (as usually in Django)?

Comment: You definitely need a spatial index, elsewise you will search the entire pointset.  Ideally spatial index will be stored and built in the database once so that you don't have to rebuild it so frequently.  CarLocation objects being stored away from the attributes may help with disk organization.  You may also consider buffering the query point and then running an intersection against the buffered query point.

Comment: @PeterSmith thx for your comment... what do you mean with "buffering the query point and then running an intersection against the buffered query point"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GeoDjango: How can I get the distance between two points?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32092584/geodjango-how-can-i-get-the-distance-between-two-points)